# django-intl-tel-input returns 404 error in the terminal?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, intl-tel-input

I'm using `Django-intl-tel-input` to make a widget in the user sign up page to choose the phone number format/country but the widget doesn't appear in the page and the terminal gives the following error :

```
Not Found: /accounts/signup/”https:

//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”
Not Found: /accounts/signup/”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”
Not Found: /accounts/signup/<link href=
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:52] "GET /accounts/signup/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 5475
Not Found: /accounts/signup/<script type=
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:52] "GET /accounts/signup/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 5493
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:52] "GET /accounts/signup/%3Clink%20href= HTTP/1.1" 404 5370
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:52] "GET /accounts/signup/%3Cscript%20type= HTTP/1.1" 404 5376
Not Found: /accounts/signup/”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:53] "GET /accounts/signup/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 5475
Not Found: /accounts/signup/”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”
[29/Jul/2019 14:10:53] "GET /accounts/signup/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery

-ui.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 5493
```

I didn't load/call any CSS or js files in this template

```
{%load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<head>>
    <link href="{{ form.media.css }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>

#content{

margin-top : 4%;
margin-left : 18%;
margin-right : 2%;
margin-bottom : 6%;

}

</style>

<div id="content">

  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    <p></p>
  </form>

</div>

<script src="{{ form.media.js }}"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
  {{ form.media.js }}
);
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and my form :

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
Telephone_num = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number', widget= IntlTelInputWidget())

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model =     MyUser
    fields =    ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'hospital', 'clinic', 'address')
```

I tried using `django-phonenumber-field` but its widget is without the countries flags and not so user-friendly I also tried

```
        widgets = {
        'Telephone_no': widgets.PhoneNumberPrefixWidget
    }
```

after adding the phone number field to the `fields` attribute but it also didn't work.